# How to deal with two Sitemaps with two different installations?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have a website that runs an onlineshop (the software is Shopware) at `example.com`. The blog is maintained with WordPress and is reachable at `example.com/blog`.

I have a robots.txt that lists the sitemap for `example.com/sitemap.xml`. Surely this sitemap does not contain the links of the `example.com/blog` WordPress pages.

How do I deal with this? I assume that the shop system can not inlude the WP sitemap, because the system does not know the WP installation exists.

1. Should I now include both Sitemaps in my `robots.txt` at `example.com/robots.txt` listing `example.com/sitemap.xml` and `example.com/blog/sitemap.xml`?
2. And should I insert both Sitemaps in Google Webmaster Tools for domain `example.com` or do I need to entries in Webmaster tools for `example.com` and `example.com/blog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think cross domain sitemap and things like that are not for you.

Google allowed to add subdirectories, and you can manage it seperatly with separate dashboard. That means you can add these kind of property in search console.

```
example.com
example.com/blog/
example.com/store/
```

1) Yes, you can add both main sitemap and blog sitemap in your robots.txt, but wait, if you gonna add both sitemap in search console, then you don't have to put anything on robots.txt. Personally I don't do that, because robots.txt should be placed on root directory, so scraper use that advantages and find out your sitemap link and find out all other links. Why we should waste our bandwidth by allowing to scrape our content.

2) Yes, that's what you need to do.

First add your site `example.com or www.example.com`

And submit your root/main sitemap.

Now add another property with `example.com/blog or www.example.com/blog`

And submit your blog sitemap. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add and verify both sites in search console. On this way you would be able to add and host cross-domain sitemaps. And Google will be able to correctly associate and analyze them, independently from where are they placed in fact. [Further info about cross domain sitemaps](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2007/10/dealing-with-sitemap-cross-submissions.html) here